# Нужно ли ставить кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Если мы пишем, к примеру, о проекте «Тайга»:

> В Тайге описано более двух десятков способов сохранения лесов Сибири.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, все названия проектов, являющиеся условными наименованиями, пишутся с заглавной буквы и в кавычках:
*в **«Тайге»** описано более двух десятков способов сохранения лесов Сибири*;
подробности технического облика **«Кедра»** пока предсказать практически невозможно;
**«Сосна»** предназначается для войсковой ПВО ([Проект «Сосна»](https://topwar.ru/156281-novosti-proekta-sosna-na-puti-v-seriju-i-v-vojska.html));
российский проект **«Шторм»**.

> Условные названия заключаются в кавычки как **при наличии родового слова, так и при его отсутствии**, ср.: «Яблоко» и партия «Яблоко», «Локомотив» и футбольный клуб «Локомотив», «Современник» и театр «Современник», «Лесные дали» и пансионат «Лесные дали», «Ромашка» и ООО «Ромашка» и т. д.

*Потому-то большую часть вешалок в «Кедре» занимают телогрейки и наряды образца этак сороковых – пятидесятых годов — все старо, пыльно, засижено мухами. Зато самые жгучие новости и сплетни черпались именно в «Кедре»* (В. Астафьев. Царь-рыба).

[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю, что если название будет на английском, то кавычки не нужно использовать?